# How do you create components.xml for debug/development in Seam

Tags: xml, seam, seam2

Has anyone created two versions of `components.xml` like the `components-dev.properties` or the other `dev` or `prod` versions?

How did you do this?

We have some custom components that we are using for Development that is created in `components.xml` that I would like to move to its own `components-dev.xml` but I don't how to do this. Any ideas?

The codes that I would like to move are generally like this:

```
<component name="fooBar" class="org.bar.FooBar" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally install a component like this:

```
<component name="fooBar" class="org.bar.FooBar" install="true" />
```

If you have a lot of components that need to be conditionally installed and you don't want to switch all of them when moving to production, you can use an entry in the components.properties file. For example:

components.properties

```
...
dev=true
...
```

components.xml

```
<components>
...
<component name="fooBar" class="org.bar.FooBar" install="@dev@" />
...
</components>
```

Now you just need to change the dev attribute.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Great tip! Thanks